# fftw library, undefined reference to `fftwf_*'

Tags: c++11, fftw

Well, it's a very strange error I met.

When I try to compile my program with the fftw library by the command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o main main.cpp BFSCcommandlineParser.cpp BFSCframe.cpp BFSCgeometry.cpp ImageIO.cpp -lfftw3 -lm
```

... I get this:

```
/tmp/cczUuTb0.o: In function `fftw_prog::fftw_prog(char const*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN9fftw_progC2EPKc[_ZN9fftw_progC5EPKc]+0x5c): undefined reference to `fftwf_import_wisdom_from_file'
/tmp/cczUuTb0.o: In function `fftw_prog::~fftw_prog()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN9fftw_progD2Ev[_ZN9fftw_progD5Ev]+0x31): undefined reference to `fftwf_export_wisdom_to_file'
/tmp/cczUuTb0.o: In function `fft<2, float, std::complex<float> >::fft(tensor<int, 2ul>, bool)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3fftILi2EfSt7complexIfEEC2E6tensorIiLm2EEb[_ZN3fftILi2EfSt7complexIfEEC5E6tensorIiLm2EEb]+0xcf): undefined reference to `fftwf_plan_dft_r2c'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3fftILi2EfSt7complexIfEEC2E6tensorIiLm2EEb[_ZN3fftILi2EfSt7complexIfEEC5E6tensorIiLm2EEb]+0x111): undefined reference to `fftwf_plan_dft_c2r'
/tmp/cczUuTb0.o: In function `fft<2, float, std::complex<float> >::~fft()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3fftILi2EfSt7complexIfEED2Ev[_ZN3fftILi2EfSt7complexIfEED5Ev]+0x25): undefined reference to `fftwf_free'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3fftILi2EfSt7complexIfEED2Ev[_ZN3fftILi2EfSt7complexIfEED5Ev]+0x35): undefined reference to `fftwf_destroy_plan'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3fftILi2EfSt7complexIfEED2Ev[_ZN3fftILi2EfSt7complexIfEED5Ev]+0x45): undefined reference to `fftwf_destroy_plan'
/tmp/cczUuTb0.o: In function `fft<2, float, std::complex<float> >::r2F()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3fftILi2EfSt7complexIfEE3r2FEv[_ZN3fftILi2EfSt7complexIfEE3r2FEv]+0x25): undefined reference to `fftwf_execute'
/tmp/cczUuTb0.o: In function `fft<2, float, std::complex<float> >::F2r()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3fftILi2EfSt7complexIfEE3F2rEv[_ZN3fftILi2EfSt7complexIfEE3F2rEv]+0x35): undefined reference to `fftwf_execute'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I thought it could be a problem of fftw itself, so I tested the library with a proram, and it worked. That means that it's not so. 
The following code is a template from my file which is the only one in my project that uses fftw.

```
template <int N, typename rT, typename FT>
        inline fft<N,rT,FT>::~fft() {
        if (data != 0) {
            if (Precision<rT>::IsFloat) {
                fftwf_free((fftwf_complex *)data);
                fftwf_destroy_plan((fftwf_plan_s*) r2Fplan);
                fftwf_destroy_plan((fftwf_plan_s*) F2rplan);
            }
            else {
                fftw_free((fftw_complex *)data);
                fftw_destroy_plan((fftw_plan_s*) r2Fplan);
                fftw_destroy_plan((fftw_plan_s*) F2rplan);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

For single precision (`float`) you need to link the `libfftwf` library, for double precision (`double`) you need the `libfftw` library. I would guess you are just linking the latter and not the former. For gcc et al the command line needs to contain `-lfftw3 -lfftw3f` if you want both double and single precision support.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried to link fftw library in different way. -lfftw3l -lfftw3f and the current one -lfftw3, print the same error.

Comment: That's still wrong, it needs to be `-lfftw3 -lfftw3f` if you want double and single precision.

Comment: OK - it's probably going to be something simple that's not obvious from your code above - I think you'll just need to use a *divide and conquer* approach until you identify the problem.

Comment: thanks, I am doing it. just need a long time to test the whole file(~1000 lines)

Comment: Are there any other errors/warnings ? In particular anything related to library not found or wrong architecture ?

Comment: It is OK now!, I need to add all the parameters, -lfftw3, -lfftw3f, -lfftw3l. I was stupid!